# HTTP Basic Auth Exclude Single File

Tags: regex, authentication, .htaccess

Part of my .htaccess file looks like this-

```
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
AuthName "Authorization Required"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
```

Doing that requires the Basic HTTP authentication for the entire directory and the directories below it as well.  However, I have a single file within that root directory, thubservice.php, that should not require the HTTP authentication.

From what I have seen, I need to use <FilesMatch />, but I cannot figure out the pattern to match all but that given file.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
AuthName "Authorization Required"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
<Files "thubservice.php">
    Satisfy Any
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

Comment: +1 what I was typing. You *could* do it with a negative lookahead like `<FilesMatch "^(?!thubservice\.php)">`, but it'd probably be less efficient. Let's not drag regexen into it until we need to.

Comment: @talyric what if file is at path/to/file.php in folder. I tried giving the path but its not working...

Comment: @Mubin Sorry, I don't know, and I don't have anything setup to try it on.

Answer (score 3):

With [Apache 2.4](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#run-time) you may want to use [Require](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require) instead:

```
<Files "thubservice.php">
    Require all granted
</Files>
```

> In 2.2, access control based on client hostname, IP address, and other characteristics of client requests was done using the directives Order, Allow, Deny, and Satisfy.
>
> In 2.4, such access control is done in the same way as other authorization checks, using the new module mod_authz_host. The old access control idioms should be replaced by the new authentication mechanisms, although for compatibility with old configurations, the new module mod_access_compat is provided.