# how to stop htaccess authentication for favicon.ico request

Tags: .htaccess, authentication, favicon

We have redirect the page from one domain to another domain, the requested domain is https(SSL certified) and its asking htaccess authentication for /favicon.ico
but the requested page is not include any code for /favicon.ico
Could you please give any solution for this? that is without asking htaccess authentication for /favicon.ico

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much the same as this question:
[HTTP Basic Auth Exclude Single File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865374/http-basic-auth-exclude-single-file)

Except that the other question is a little more abstract, but should fit your problem as well.